# from ekwos to ippo : transition from kw to p in greek

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, greek

I can't understand how the transition from kappa-digamma to pi-pi happened in the transition from ekwos (same etymology as latin equus) to ippo.

I mean how did the prononciation change ? Because is it a matter of prononciation ?

Comment: It is a matter of pronunciation, presumably the labial part of /kw/ becoming stronger and eventually the velar part being lost. It might seem unlikely, but it appears to have happened at least four times independently and at widely differing periods in various IE languages: in pre-Greek as you say; in Oscan; in P-Celtic (Welsh etc); and in Romanian.

Comment: Also note that this seems to be on-topic both here and on Latin.SE (which also covers Greek), so both are viable places to ask questions like this in the future! (Nothing wrong posting it here though)

Comment: I completely deny that I'm here because I thought HNQ was advertising a linguistics question about Ewoks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is, there was never a digamma in *hippos* in the first place! (At least, not as far back as we have evidence for: there may have been one earlier than that.)

Early Greek, like Latin, had a set of *labiovelar consonants*. In other words, what the Romans wrote as *qu* and linguists write as `/kʷ/` wasn't treated as a combination of `/k/` and `/w/` (kappa-digamma): it was a single phoneme in its own right.

(As a note, the tradition among Greek scholars is to write this single phoneme as *q* or `/q/`, based on how the Romans did it, even though this doesn't line up with the IPA. Confusing, but it's what we're stuck with now, so *in this answer `q` always means a voiceless labiovelar stop*. Some people even call it "qoppa", the name of an unrelated Greek letter, which is just outright a bad idea if you want people to understand you.)

In the oldest attested stages of Greek, the Linear B tablets from Crete, we can see that there was indeed a *q*: the word for "horse" is written  *i-qo*, which represents *hiqqos* (*h*, double consonants, and final *-s* weren't represented in this writing system). It's not clear where the *hi* came from, since we don't see anything similar in Latin or other languages, but that's a separate question.

But the *q* sound was never completely comfortable in Greek. It's not one of the easier or more common sounds in the world, and requires you to do something with your lips *and* with your soft palate at the same time. So over the years, Greek disposed of it, replacing it with other sounds.

In Attic in particular, *q* could turn into either *p* (keeping only the lip part), *k* (keeping only the soft palate part), or *t* (averaging the two).

- Next to *u*, it became *k* (the "boukolos rule")
- Before *e* or *i*, it became *t*
- Elsewhere, it became *p*

This is why you see *tin-* "pay" next to *poin-* "fine", or *thein-* "kill (v)" next to *phon-* "slaughter (n)", or *bou-kol-* "cowherd" next to *amphi-pol-* "attendant", and so on. Note that these rules are only for Attic: this *wasn't* consistent across dialects. Compare Latin *quis* "who" and *-que* "and", Mycenaean (Linear B) *qis*, *-qe*, Attic *tis*, *-te*, Doric *kis*, *-ke*.

In the word for "horse", the *q* fell into the "otherwise" clause, so it changed from *hiqqos* to *hippos*.

---

P.S. While this sound change may look odd, it's not uncommon in the world. Both Proto-Italic and Proto-Celtic split into two branches each, one preserving *q*, the other turning it into *p*. And much later, Romanian did the same to all of Latin's *q*s.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that while there may not be a recorded stage of Greek where *hippos* had a separate /w/ sound, from a comparative standpoint, a cluster /ḱ.w/ rather than a unitary phoneme /kʷ/ is reconstructed for Proto-Indo-European, to account for stuff like the śv cluster in Sanskrit *aśva.* The coalescence of this cluster to a labiovelar would have only happened after the split between the ancestor of Sanskrit and the ancestor of Greek.

Comment: This was common enough to get a generalized name for the phenomenon; I was taught that Greek was a "labializing dialect" of PIE, which meant that the original labiovelar consonants had smeared across the oral space from lips to velum like soluble fractions displayed in a chromatography chart.

Comment: @jlawler Interesting! That's not a term I've heard before

Comment: well, if not qoppa, then how was `q` written in Q-Greek?

Comment: @vectory Mycenaean was the only dialect that preserved `/q/` in writing, and it predated the Greek alphabet as we know it today; it used a syllabic writing system, where e.g.  meant `/qe/` and  meant `/qo/`. ((Where `/q/` means the labiovelar again.))

Answer (score 4):

If you analyze phonemes into components, /kw/ is velar+stop+labialized. Then if you remove "velar", then you have stop+labialized = /p/. So basically, the change /kw/ > /p(p)/ amounts to a weakening of velarization.